# Java Record in Valhalla

Tags: java

I have been using record from Java 17 for sometime and I like it.

```
record Something(int a, int b){}
```

I also noticed recently that `Project Valhalla` introduces value type

```
value record Something(int a, int b){}
```

Now I am confused. record was supposed to be value classes. Then what is the point of adding the `value`? What is the problem valhalla trying to solve?

Comment: Records ([JEP 395](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395)) are carriers of immutable data. Value objects ([draft](https://openjdk.org/jeps/8277163)) are identity-less objects (i.e. their identity is defined by their field values).

Comment: Here's a blog post that should shed some light on the differences between records, value types and value records: https://www.beyondjava.net/records-vs-value-types.